# Pre-selecting a select item using AngularJS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following objects and properties:

```
User - TitleID
     - FirstName
     - Surname
     - EmailAddress

Titles - CodeID
       - Description
```

The user's title should be preselected in a select element which also contains all the other Titles from the Titles.

Although I can get all the titles to display in the select box, I cannot get it to pre-select the correct (or indeed any) title from the select box when editing a user.

This is what I have so far:

```
<select ng-model="user.TitleID" ng-options="title.CodeID as title.Description for title in titles track by title.CodeID">
```

How do I go about getting the correct title preselected with this relational data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a potential bug in Angular where `track by` and `as` don't work together in `ngOptions`.

[GitHub Issue #6564](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564)

Remove the track by and it'll work...

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DJVZ/)